# HTML img element nested within an a element.. help for a noobie :)

Tags: html, nested

So I have created a white box around an image. But the problem is I cant click through the image to the page. I know the problem is that I didnt close the img tag, then open a second a tag inside it. But I cant figure out how to do it.

Here is my code

```
<a class="panel panel-negative-lg paddingAll-l" title="Partners" href="/en/customers/">
<img class="img-responsive" width="145" height="87" <a href="http://http://www.nacbhdd.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/jtky2w.jpg" border="0" width="145px" height="87px" align="center" hspace="10px" alt="NACBHDD">
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
<a class="panel panel-negative-lg paddingAll-l" title="Partners" href="/en/customers/">
<img class="img-responsive" width="145" height="87" <a href="https://www.nasmhpd.org/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2mwf59g.jpg" border="0" width="145px" height="87px" align="center" alt="NASMHPD">
</a>
```

This is what I want my final product to look like
[IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/i78yvs.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, my friend:

```html
<div>
  <a class="panel panel-negative-lg paddingAll-l" title="Partners" href="/en/customers/">
    <a href="http://http://www.nacbhdd.org/" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/jtky2w.jpg" border="0" width="145px" height="87px" align="center" hspace="10px" alt="NACBHDD">
    </a>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <a class="panel panel-negative-lg paddingAll-l" title="Partners" href="/en/customers/">
    <a href="https://www.nasmhpd.org/" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2mwf59g.jpg" border="0" width="auto" height="87px" align="center" alt="NASMHPD">
    </a>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the time you took to help. There is just one problem. The white encasing box around the image now flattened out. It is not responsive to the image size. Thanks!!

Comment: I've set the second image's width to `auto`, is this what you are looking for?